# Get the focused "container control" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a complex application with many fields and to little room for labels describing exactly what should be the input of a given control. To tackle this problem I tried using the tooltip of each control for descriptions of the elements. As those tooltips are getting in the way and are disapearing once the user starts typing, I dedicated an area of my application to display the tooltip of the focused element. This works pretty well except for more complex controls that contain other controls, e.g. the `DatePicker`, as the focused element will be the `PARTextBox` of the `DatePicker`. Here is a minimal example demonstrating that problem:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel>  
    <TextBox ToolTip="TextBox ToolTip" />
    <DatePicker ToolTip="DatePicker ToolTip" />
    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=(FocusManager.FocusedElement).ToolTip}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Is there a general approach to solve this focusing problem and display the tooltip of such a "composite" control (hence for all such controls, not only `DatePicker`)?

Comment: This is a big problem in WPF. It's a big problem for tab ordering because you can't tell a control to have a TabIndex if that control is a container control. So, if you need to find out what container the focused control is in, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd go for this approach:

1. Create an [Attached Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) that will provide the descriptive text for the control
2. Have the attached property class also take a binding to your VM property for the descriptive text
3. Bind the descriptive text viewmodel property to a label / textblock
4. The attached property then listens out for when the control gets focus and just updates the relevant binding.

So in the XAML at least it could look something like this:

```
<TextBox local:DescriptiveText="This textbox takes some input" local:DescriptiveTarget="{Binding DescriptiveText} />
<Label Content="{Binding DescriptiveText} />
```